# What video player to use for streaming within Ionic 2?

Tags: html, video, ionic2, http-live-streaming

I need to build an APP that would index videos (m3u8) from an API and allow to play them within the application itself. Only plugin I could make work and that seems to work in both iOS and Android is cordova-plugin-streaming-media, but has some issues with HLS streaming (https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media/issues/77).

Any suggestions? I would like it to support fullscreen. Tried videojs and couldn't get it to work in fullscreen within the device.

Thanks!